# Changing background of HTML select item doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with several options, the background of these options changes dynamically in javascript code. This works fine in Chrome and Opera but not Firefox. Here is the HMTL-Element:

```html
<div style=" text-align:center;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-right: 10px">
    <select id="measure" style="width:90%" name="measure" class="dropdownS" required></select>
    <select id="duration" style="width:40%" name="date" class="dropdownS" required></select>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```css
.dropdownS {
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

And the line of code for changing the background:

```
const selYear = document.getElementById('duration');

let opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test');
opt.style.backgroundColor = '#90EE90';
opt.value = 'Test';
selYear.appendChild(opt);
```

How can I make it work in Firefox too?

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]? Preferable as a snippet here in the question. In your current code, `years`, `k` and `selYear` are not defined.

Comment: Changed some stuff around, trying to get a codepen working too atm.

Comment: OK. I don't see much difference between the browsers, tbh. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rv54csb/) I made, the select itself has its default background and the options that are not selected in the dropdown have the lightgreen background. In both browsers.

Comment: Must be a problem with my Firefox then, your example doesn't work for me.